# Black Fill in my plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using the following code and when it compiles the result is not what i expect.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar,enlargelimits=0.15]
\addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
    {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};

\addplot
[draw=black,pattern=horizontal lines dark blue] 
coordinates 
    {(3,5) (5,10) (15,15) (20,20) (35,25)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
```

Particularly, i got this :

[image]

instead of this :

[image]

Finally, I use the code below for packages and package settings.

```
%----------------------------------------Tikz-------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
```

Comment1:

The results of `\listfiles` are :

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

  isorot.sty    2000/02/15 v2.1 ISO rotation package
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
polyglossia.sty    2013/06/27 v1.33.4 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  hypcap.sty    2011/02/16 v1.11 Adjusting the anchors of captions (HO)
gloss-greek.ldf    polyglossia: module for greek
xgreek-fixes.def
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
   mcode.sty    2012/08/31 2.3
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
listings.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2013/08/26 1.5b listings configuration
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2013/10/03 v1.9 Data Visualization (1.9)
 pgf-pie.sty    2011/10/02 v0.2 Some LaTeX macros for pie chart by using PGF/Ti
kz package.
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
scalefnt.sty    
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and post the results into your question - it'll help show users what versions of files you have, which seems like it will be relevant to your question :)

Comment: I just add it as first comment on my question. Thanks :-)

Comment: Some time ago, I stumbled about the same - until Till Tantau pointed out that I have used a driver (`dvipdfm`, I suppose) for which these patterns were not implemented at that time. Can you tell us how you compile the file? And: does the errors persist if you try it with `pdflatex`?

Comment: I just compiled it with `lualatex`, because i have greek text which `pdflatex` can't compiled it right.

But now i have an another problem that i don't expect, index names from Greek words become Unknown words like `|$|%^$@$~`.

Comment: So the tikz picture compiles with lualatex and/or pdflatex, right? In this case it is a driver problem.

Comment: Dear @ChristianFeuersänger look at my answer below, because i solve it.

It doesn't need to use lualatex, only add `fill=color` command.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from your comments and your answer, I conclude that you have

- PGF 2.10
- xelatex

In this case I get the log message

```
Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not support patterns. This warning is given only once on input line 18.
```

The solution is to upgrade to PGF 3.0.0 (the current stable of PGF). Then you can compile patterns in `xelatex` .

Note that your solution with `fill=color` does not produce the correct patterns on my machine. The only solution is to use either `PGF 3.0.0` or, if you really want to stick with the old PGF, use another driver (i.e. `pdflatex` / `dvips` instead of `xelatex`)

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found after hours of search is :

```
\addplot
    [draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue, fill=red, fill opacity=0.55] 
    coordinates
        {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
```

And finally i could continue compile my code with ***xelatex***!