# Why do I get black areas instead of pattern fills when compiling with xelatex?

Tags: pgfplots, xetex

I want to draw this picture with TikZ. I've used the following code. But the outcome was not good (fig1). While the Fig 2 is the correct form.

I do not know where is the problem?
**My texlive version is 2012.**

Please guide me in this regard.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[area legend,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
domain=0:1,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},
anchor=north west},
axis on top,xmin=0]
\addplot[pattern=crosshatch dots,
pattern color=blue,draw=blue,
samples=500]
{sqrt(x)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
pattern color=blue!30!white,
draw=blue!30!white]
{x^2} \closedcycle;
\addplot[red,line legend] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\legend{$\sqrt x$,$x^2$,$x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you compile your document? Do you use `xelatex`, by any chance, or `pdflatex`?

Comment: Impressive @Jake.  I'm getting the left figure using xelatex and the right figure using pdflatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. In your particular example it would help to know what tikz libraries you are using etc --- and how you want to compile it as this seem relevant.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Black fill in my plots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194458/2552). The short of it: You'll need to update your PGF package if you want to use `xelatex` with patterns.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-math}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-0}
\FPeval\XMax{6}
\FPeval\YMin{0-0}
\FPeval\YMax{36}

\FPeval\XOL{0} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/3} % of DeltaY


\FPeval\DeltaX{1}
\FPeval\DeltaY{5}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=8cm
\newlength\Height\Height=12cm

\newlength\llx\llx=-25pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-25pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt

\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
    Dx=\DeltaX,
    Dy=\DeltaY,
    labels=none,
    subticks=5,
    tickwidth=.4pt,
    subtickwidth=.2pt,
    tickcolor=Orange!20,
    subtickcolor=ForestGreen!20,
    xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
    yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
    subticksize=1,
}

\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=200,
}

\def\f{x^2}
\def\g{x}
\def\h{sqrt(x)}

\begin{document}
\pslegend[rt]{%
    \color{Red}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{Red} $y=x^2$\\
    \color{Green}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{Green} $y=x$ \\
    \color{Blue}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{Blue} $y=\sqrt x$
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        Dx=\DeltaX,
        Dy=\DeltaY,
        linecolor=lightgray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psaxes[style=mygrid](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[linecolor=Red]{0}{\XMax}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=Green]{0}{\XMax}{\g}
    \psplot[linecolor=Blue]{0}{\XMax}{\h}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]